# Trying to make a csv, output keeps putting data on a new line

Tags: c++, csv

I was using this code:

```
char *buffer2;

int tagpos;// pretend I set the value somewhere else, but its an int.

buffer2=new char[tagpos+1];

outfile.write(buffer2,tagpos);
```

and my data would put the first result into my csv on the first line, then the next time I called this funciton, it would put it on the next line even without adding any \n our << endl How do I stop this from happening?

Here is an example output.

```
Pacific Group
1111 S Elm St,

(555) 723-4660Mt. Tabor Group
1111 SE Belmont St,

(555) 536-7689Northwest Clinic PC
1111 NW Pettygrove St,

(555) 223-6223Northwest Pharmacy
1111 NW Garden Valley Blvd , Suite 111,
```

This is the html that its being scraped from:

```
<span class="listing-address adr">
<span class="street-address">
1111 E Barnett Rd,
</span>
<span class="city-state">
```

Comment: Program it in C and use "fprintf()" instead? ;)

Comment: Some types for those variables would be helpful...  so would some context of how you are using that function (e.g. what is the content of its parameters)

Comment: Does `buffer2` have a newline?  And just curious, why are you not using the `outfile << buffer2` syntax?

Comment: I wouldn't include that real data in this example. I would suggest using some dummy data instead for posting here.

Comment: How does the data in buffer2 get populated?  Maybe wherever you are reading it from contains `\n` at the end of each record?

Comment: I actually did change it to outfile << buffer2; but same problem. I even open in ios::binary. Same problem.

Comment: Its a scraper, it gets populated from an html file but the data right before is just an, '>' bracket.

Comment: There is even two new lines after the address.

Comment: The only place there is not a new line is after the phone number. The business name creates a new line after it, the address creates two new lines and then the phone number does it properly.

Comment: How about right after the data?  Are you parsing the html on your own or using a 3rd-party library?

Comment: on my own. Just nested if statements looking for a few key letters before my data then I count the distance between the brackets.

Comment: I did a little debugging, there is definitely something wrong with how big I'm making buffer2. It appears to be too big on the address and phone number by a few. There must be some data leaking in from existing memory causing this newline.

Comment: Attila, I think you've got the right answer. I think there is a new line in the html. Make a proper answer and I'll choose it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your given sample data

```
<span class="street-address">
1111 E Barnett Rd,
</span>
```

it looks like your input data contains the newline characters.  It will depend on how the XML is read, but the last character before the `</span>` in this example is a newline character.  There's also one just before the `1111 E Barnett Rd,`.